# Create an MSVC library that MinGW can link

Tags: visual-c++, mingw, static-libraries, name-mangling

I'm trying to create a static library using MS Visual Studio 2012 that MinGW will be able to link to (I'm handling the MinGW-side of this process with Code::Blocks).

To avoid [name-mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) problems, the library interface is declared within `extern "C"` blocks and uses only [data types common to both C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure). Despite this precaution, MinGW gives undefined reference errors when attempting to compile a project that links to the library.

The library file is compiled in VS 2012 from two files, LibTest.h and LibTest.cpp (these are simplified examples that exhibit the problem).

```
// LibTest.h

#ifndef LIBTEST_H
#define LIBTEST_H

extern "C" {

int Test(int input);

}

#endif
```

---

```
// LibTest.cpp

#include "LibTest.h"

extern "C" {

int Test(int input){
    return (input + 5);
}

}
```

VS 2012 compiles this as a static library (LibTest.lib) with no complaints. My test program for MinGW is as follows:

```
// LibTest.lib is linked in the project settings
#include "LibTest.h" // Same LibTest.h as above

int main(){

    int x = 5;
    int a = Test(x);

    return 0;
}
```

When I attempt to compile this, the process fails with an undefined reference error (the same error that would be generated by attempting to link a name-mangled library). I would expect the use of `extern "C"` to prevent name-mangling issues, but as this is the first time I've attempted to create a cross-compiler-compatible library I've probably missed something else.

Any suggestions or comments would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you post the exact error message so everyone can see exactly what name MinGW is looking for?  It might also be instructive to post the output of `dumpbin /symbols LibTest.lib` so we can see what names are in the library created by MSVC.

Comment: The exact error from MinGW is: `obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp (.text+0x16): undefined reference to Test` The output of `dumpbin /symbols` is just "File Type: LIBRARY". Interestingly, `reimp` doesn't produce any output when run on LibTest.lib either.

Comment: It appears that the library VS 2012 is producing is invalid in some way. When attempting to link to the library (with the `extern "C"` blocks removed just in case they're causing a problem) from another VS 2012 project, the build fails with `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl Test(int)" (?Test@@YAHH@Z)` I'm unsure of what could be wrong with the library; my procedure for creating it matches that detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms235627%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: What happens if you build the library from the command line: `cl /c libtest.cpp && lib libtest.obj`

Comment: Building it from the command line works, both in general and specifically for the purpose of creating a library that works with MinGW. Evidently something's amiss with my VS 2012 project settings. MinGW produces the warning `Warning: .drectve /DEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES" unrecognized` when linking the library, but the resulting program works. Thanks for your help, @MichaelBurr!

Answer (score 0):

I would say microsoft compilers needs __declspec(dllexport) !

Here is a msdn link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/a90k134d.aspx